Computing the expected value use p.g.f., what can go wrong?
Let $X$ be a random variable with values in the non-negative integers. Assume that $E[X]$ is finite.
Let $p(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n z^n$ be the probability generating function of $X$, $p_n=P(X=n)$.
It is known that the radius of convergence $R$ of this series is at least $1$. Let's assume that $R=1$ because this is the only case where my question is interesting.
I've learned that $E[X] = \lim_{t\to 1^{-}} p'(t)$. Let's call this Theorem A.
Now comes the question

Why not just say $E[X]=p'(1)$, i.e. what are the different possibilities that this can fail.

Well, $p'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n \cdot n \cdot z^{n-1}$ (radius of convergence still $1$). Plugging in $z=1$ in this power series always results in $E[X]$. So I guess I should think of $p'(z)$ in this context not as a formal power series, but as a meromorphic function that is defined by this power series in the open unit disc.

Is this right so far?

So, the beef of the question:


Is it possible for the meromorphic functon $p'(z)$ to converge at $z=1$ to a finite value different from $E[X]$?
Is it possible for the meromorphic function $p'(z)$ not to converge at $z=1$?


Any example would have to have $p'(z)$ discontinuous at $z=1$.


What do you mean by "$p'(1)$"?

The power series $p(z)$ defines an analytic function in the open unit disk $D$; its term-by-term derivative $p'(z)$ does likewise. In what region do you conceive of $p'$ being meromorphic?

The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty np_n$ (the term-by term derivative of $p'(z)$ at $z=1$) does converge, because $X$ is assumed to have a finite mean, and (Abel's theorem) $E(X)=\lim_{z\to 1,z\in[0,1)}p'(z)$.



I am starting  to understand. Is it the case that there's no $p'(1)$ because $p'$ is not defined in an open neighbourhood of $1$? What about the one-sided left derivative to p, evaluated at $1$. Is this equal to $E[X]$? I guess what I'm missing the most is an example where Abel's theorem $E[X]=\lim_{1^-}p'(z))$ is useful.

You have both $E(X) = \lim_{z\to 1,z\in[0,1)}p'(z)$ and
$$
E(X) =\lim_{z\to 1,z\in[0,1)}{1-p(z)\over 1-z}.
$$
(The former is likely to be easier to implement, if you have a reasonable expression for $p(z)$, $0\le z<1$.) For the second limit, notice that
$$
{1-p(z)\over 1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n\cdot{1-z^n\over 1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty p_n.
$$
As $z$ increases to $1$ along the interval $[0,1)$, the sum on the right increases to
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty p_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X>k)=E(X).
$$
